# Spring data solr - multilingual support

Tags: spring, solr, multilingual, spring-data-solr

I've to implement multilingual search capability & I was reading thro' Spring data Solr but couldn't find much details on how to implement multilingual queries using Spring data Solr.

Consider there's a Solr collection with dynamic fields & we're indexing documents based on locale. Now if I use Spring data Solr, I'll have to create an entity with fields matching all locales.

E.g. field defined in Solr schema.xml

...
...

dynamicField name="name_en_us"           type="text_en_us"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  required="false" docValues="false" multiValued="false"

dynamicField name="name_fr_fr"           type="text_fr_fr"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  required="false" docValues="false" multiValued="false"

...
...

'name' field will be added in the entity as:
name_en_us,
name_fr_fr,
name_en_uk,
...
...

Is there any way we can do this dynamically? I mean having only 1 field name in entity & based on locale fetch the the documents from Solr using Spring data?

Please suggest.